# Selenium Grid: Tests are running in sequence at on node at one time

Tags: selenium-webdriver

> I Need to run a sequence of 2 tests in parallel in 2 node machine at
>   same time.But currently 1st test gets executed in 1st node and after
>   the execution is finished,second test gets started in second node. Max
>   Instance for each node is set to 1.
>
> Here is my suite file:
>
> ```
> <!-- <package name="com.fico.triad.test.ApportionmentMethods" />
> <package name="com.fico.triad.test.Audit" />  <package name="com.fico.triad.test.AuditTrial" />  -->  <package
> ```
>
> name="com.fico.triad.test.AuditTrialChangeDetailLog" />
>
> I am using Thread local here also.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want it on same machine ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `TestNG` framework with `Selenium`. Just refer below **testng.xml** file and edit your classes name accordingly :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Parallel test suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Test 1">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.sd.selenium.FirstTestSelenium" />
            <class
                name="com.sd.selenium.practice.Monday_Test_Selenium_Till_Scrum_Call" />
        </classes>

    </test>
</suite>
```

**Note:**

1) Two classes must be in `different packages`.
2) You need to run entire project as `TestNG Suite` by selecting this xml file as your suite . Refer below image :  [image]