# How to Login to a website parallel with different users in Selenium Web driver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, parallel-testing

Here is my scenario that needs to be automated:

1. I need to login into website with different users say 'gmail'.
2. Perform different operation say 'compose','change settings', etc.
3. Then logout.

I need all the above steps to be performed in parallel.

- class1 - Opens multiple Chrome drivers.
- class2 - Methods to perform operations such as navigate, enter text, clicks etc.
- class3 - contains Test cases.

Below is my code:

```
public class1 {
    public static RemoteWebDriver[] driver = new RemoteWebDriver[3];
    public void openBrowser(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
        for(i = 0;i<2;i++){
            driver[i] = new ChromeDriver();
            driver[i].manage().window().maximize();
        }
    }
}

public class2 extends class1 {
    public void click() {...}
    public void setText() {...}
}

public class2 {
    @Test
    public void test1() {...}
    public void test2() {...}
}
```

With my above code, I m able to open multiple browser instances with different session id's.

Then, operations are done in same browser multiple times ie Navigates to `gmail.com` 3 times, then, enters username 3 times (user1user1user1).

Its not running in 3 different instance of browser.

Kindly help me to achieve this.

Comment: Can you consider showing us your work please?

Comment: @DebanjanB, Do u want to show my complete coding ?

Comment: It would be helpful for the SO community volunteers to suggest you the most efficient solution if you put your exact work here instead of the prototype. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using TestNG, so you can create this using `parallel` attribute in your XML. There are a lot of tutorials on the internet about this. [This](http://www.guru99.com/sessions-parallel-run-and-dependency-in-selenium.html) might be of interest for you.

Also [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/nSDh5rKQXQ8) google group thread has a very good discussion about this.

A detailed blog post is [here](https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/).

Comment: Thanks!!!.. your detailed blog link is useful. But still, i was unable to execute in parallel. I implemented the same technique for Suites. No use. I used 'ISuiteListener' interface instead of IInvokedMethodListener. Here in my scenario, i dont need classes/methods to run in parallel, i need suites to run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](http://www.guru99.com/parameterization-using-xml-and-dataproviders-selenium.html) link for how to pass different credentials for different browser nodes at the same time and refer my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283766/selenium-grid-tests-are-running-in-sequence-at-on-node-at-one-time/44285095#44285095) link for how to test multiple test scripts at the same time on different browser nodes. Let me know in case of any issues .